# What is the sentence structure for this verse in John Keats' "The day is gone, and all its sweets are gone!"?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, poetry

He writes:

> When the dusk holiday—or holinight [—][some versions put another em dash here] 
> Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave 
> The woof of darkness thick, for hid delight,

Should I read a pause, like:

> When the dusk begins to weave (the) holiday or holinight of fragrant-curtain'd love **(;)** The woof of darkness (implied *made*) thick, for hid delight
> ⠀

?

Otherwise I can't make sense of it:

- Maybe:

> When the *dusk* (adjective) *holiday—or holinight* (subject) begins to weave *the woof of darkness* (object) thick (predicative of the object) of fragrant-curtain'd love

- Or:

> When *the dusk* (subject?) begins to weave *holiday—or holinight* (object?) / *the woof of darkness* (object? Which one?) thick (predicative of the object) of fragrant-curtain'd love

- Maybe there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: *[the day] vanishes when the holinight begins to weave the woof of darkness for hidden delight...*

Comment: I really think you need to work out the overall meaning of this sonnet before figuring out how to parse the sentences.

Comment: It's a simple complex sentence: The boys are swimming and the girls are skating.

Comment: Your title does not cohere with your question...

Comment: @Lambie It certainly does, as long as you take notice of the apostrophe, which leads one to the conclusion that the quoted bit is the title of the poem, not the example from it.

Comment: @PeterShor  You cannot get the "overall" meaning until you parse the text.

Comment: I mean, you can understand the octet of a sonnet, say, and have a very clear idea of the meaning, but then come to some gnarly syntax later in the poem, so that the meaning of a particular sentence remains somewhat opaque or ambiguous. That's especially true of poems written at a time when subject-object-verb inversion is not uncommon.

Comment: How, here, could sentence structure or content influence each other? 

In like vein, why does 'The day is gone, and all its sweets are gone!' appear only in the Question title and not the exposition?

Comment: The dog is gone and all the puppies are gone. What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I understand the clause beginning *when the dusk...* to be a modifier of **shut of eve**:

```
    ...  at shut of eve
When the dusk holiday or holinight
Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave
The woof of darkness thick for hid delight
```

Compare:

at break of day when cock begins to crow

or

at midday when your shadow disappears

On first reading I understand **dusk** to be a noun acting as modifier of "holiday", which is the subject of the verb phrase "begins to weave" whose object is "the woof" and *thick* being an object complement like "tie it **tight**", i.e. weave the woof so that the fabric is thick, no longer see-through.  It is a "woof of darkness" being woven into the "curtain" fabric of the evening.

The preposition **for** might be paraphrased as "for the purposes of" (hidden delight).

If **dusk** is to be the subject of "begins to weave" with **holiday** the object, the clause beginning "the woof" would have to be an absolute construction (the woof [being] thick):

```
...  at shut of eve
When the dusk holiday or holinight
Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave,
The woof of darkness thick for hid delight
```

And one might wish for this reading that these lines read "when dusk the holiday" instead of "when the dusk holiday":

```
...  at shut of eve
When dusk the holiday or holinight
Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave,
The woof of darkness thick for hid delight
```

The locution **weave the woof** is well attested.  But  of course **weave** can be intransitive. So I suppose the choice comes down to deciding whether "the dusk holiday" makes any sense as a noun phrase or "holiday--or holinight-- of fragrant-curtain'd love" *without any article* makes sense as a noun-phrase so that it can stand as the object of **weave**. The locution **make holiday of (something)** [i.e. to treat it as an occasion for fun or as a break from serious business or to treat it with less seriousness than it deserves]  is attested in the late 18th and early 19th century; ***weave* holiday of fragrant-curtain'd love** would be possible by analogy, though without the negative connotations perhaps.

Do you have an image of the manuscript?

Comment: I think that's a bit awry there. *Dusk* here is the (slightly antiquated) [adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dusk), not the noun. It's modifying the head noun *holiday* in the noun phrase *the dusk holiday*. (I think, anyway)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  OP wondered if **dusk**  was noun and subject of **begins to weave** with "[the] holiday or holinight of fragrant-curtain'd love" as direct object of that verb.  I took **dusk** to be a modifier of **holiday** so I'd accept **dusk** as the antiquated *adj.*   The harder nut, IMO, is **weave**. Hard to say if **weave** is transitive (direct object **the woof of darkness**) or intransitive, with the final line "the woof of darkness thick for hid delight" an absolute construction. Thoughts?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — *[The day and all that]: Vanished at shut of eve[ning], [which is] when the dusk[y] holiday[/holinight] of love begins to weave [thick] the woof of darkness...* I think of *dusk* as an attributive noun but it could be the antiquated adjective all the same. And *weave* is a transitive verb. Dusk is the last thing between day and night (the shut of evening). And dusk is love’s holy time (read as “holy” because *missal*).

Comment: @TinfoilHat I agree completely with your interpretation. But if 'dusk' *were* a noun, a whole single-noun NP in fact, then Tim might be theoretically be right and the clause might have an unusual SOV order. But that would give you *holiday* without a determiner, which would be a bit odd, and the sentence would be extremely ambiguous, so I'm pretty sure that *dusk* is attributive here. Personally, I think if *dusk* were an attributive noun *dusk evening* would be a bit of a weird combination, but if *dusk* is the adjective meaning *dark* or *shadowy*, that fits much better. Not absolutely sure.

Comment: @TinfoilHat As for *weave*, yes it's usually transitive, but it can easily be used intransitively. A: "What have you been doing all afternoon?" B: "Weaving". But again, it would just be a bit of a weird thing to say about the evening. "*The evening has been weaving*" is an odd and difficult to interpret thing to say, but "*The evening has been weaving a shadowy veil across the land*" and the like makes more sense, so I'm with you that *weave* must be transitive here.

Comment: The actual object of **weave**, if it is taken to be transitive here, is **woof**,  the crosswise yarn. **weave the woof** is well-attested. But the grammatical subject of a transitive **weave** (the weaver) is not at all clear to me:  **the dusk holiday--or holinight of fragrant-curtain'd love**. Is "holinight" doing the weaving?

Comment: And why is **holinight** said to be "fragrant-**curtain'd**"?  Is night weaving itself? How elaborate is the metaphor?

Comment: @Tim: It's not the *holinight* that is *fragrant-curtan'd* but *love*.  Just like in *the bowl of delicious strawberries*, it's not the *bowl* that is *delicious* but the *strawberries.* In what kind of English grammatical construction *noun1 of adjective noun2* does the *adjective* end up modifying *noun1*?

Comment: @PeterShor: I was asking about the reflexivity of the metaphor, which seems to bend back upon itself.  Holinight is, and is making, love's curtain. It is a **holinight of ... love** and the love is "curtain'd  and what is curtaining love is the darkness being woven by **holinight**.  *a night of love* is not the same as *a bowl of strawberries*. With the berries it is a partitive genitive (a portion of something) whereas with **night of love** the genitive marks an essential attribute, as an "act of generosity" is a *generous act*,

Answer (score 0):

["The day is gone, and all its sweets are gone!"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50374/the-day-is-gone-and-all-its-sweets-are-gone)
BY JOHN KEATS

The day is gone, - *It’s dark*

and all its sweets are gone! – *and the girl’s gone*

*[glowing description of the girl]*

Vanish’d unseasonably at shut of eve, - *Disappointingly, she went just as it got dark*

When the dusk holiday – or holinight - * - *

Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave

The woof of darkness thick, for hid delight, - *and just as the night was about to make things interesting*

But, as I’ve read love’s missal through to-day, - *Meh! I’ve got Love’s message*

He’ll let me sleep, seeing I fast and pray. – *Yeah, well It's not going to stop my getting a night’s sleep seeing as I’m being celebate and praying that things will be different tomorrow.*

**When the dusk holiday – or holinight - Of fragrant-curtain’d love begins to weave The woof of darkness thick, for hid delight,** ->

**Just when dusk was starting to weave the woof of thick darkness from fragrant curtained love, so that there would be some intimacy.**

curtained love – romance inside a room made private by curtains. Curtains drawn because it’s dark.